# psexec is not recognized as an internal or external command while running a batch file from windows scheduler

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, psexec

I have a `.bat` file to start the Windows service. When I run it manually it works fine but if I run it from task scheduler it gives the following error.

```
'psexec64.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
The system cannot find the file sessid.txt.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I tried with the following scenarios

- Tried with both `psexec64.exe` and `psexec.exe`
- Added the `psexec` path in environment variables

still no luck

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set username=user1
set usr=bdomain\user1
set password=2018
set machine=192.168.1.16

psexec64.exe \\%machine% -u %usr% -p %password% query session %username%>D:\Service_Start\sessid.txt

set /a counter=0
for /F "tokens=* skip=1" %%a in (sessid.txt) do (
    for %%b in (%%a) do (
        set /a counter+=1
        if !counter! == 3 (
            psexec64.exe \\192.168.1.16 -u bdomain\user1 -p 2018 -i %%b -d net start OracleServiceTest
        )
    )
)
pause;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modified the code as below and it's working

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

                                  set username=user1
                                  set usr=bdomain\user1
                                  set password=2018
                                  set machine=192.168.1.16

                                  D:\PSTools\psexec64.exe \\%machine% -u %usr% -p %password% query session %username%>D:\Service_Start\sessid.txt

                                  set /a counter=0
                                  for /F "tokens=* skip=1" %%a in (D:\Service_Start\sessid.txt) do (
                                  for %%b in (%%a) do (
                                  set /a counter+=1
                                  if !counter! == 3 ( 

                                   D:\PSTools\psexec64.exe \\192.168.1.16 -u bdomain\user1 -p 2018 -i %%b -d net start OracleServiceTest

                                  )
                                  )
                                  )
```